# Unable to start simple Erlang cowboy application

Tags: erlang, rebar, cowboy

I am completely new to Erlang, apart from reading the odd book and website on syntax and basic structure. I decided to throw myself into it a bit and create a simple web server using cowboy. Every time I try to run the application I receive

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{application,ensure_all_started,[dayamo_app],[]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
```

As far as I am aware, having Google for the answer, this is stating that `ensure_all_started` is not defined on `application` and therefore throwing a fit. This is where I get stumped. Could anybody take a look at my very small codebase in case there is anything really obvious I am doing wrong.

I have created a simple makefile which will install dependencies, compile and run the application. You simply run `make && make run`

[The erlang repo on github](https://github.com/Dayamo/dayamo)

Comment: What version of Erlang are you running? This function was added in Erlang/OTP R16B02.

Comment: Erlang R16B01 (erts-5.10.2) [source-bdf5300] [64-bit] That may explain it

Comment: That definitely explains it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502783/erlang-how-to-load-applications-with-their-dependencies, if you need to use R16B01. But if you have the choice, just use Erlang 18.

Comment: Thanks. Thing is I don't remember actually install erlang on my system so perhaps OS X shipped with an older version. Just installed the latest through MacPorts and it works perfectly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments above this was resolved by updating the version of Erlang OTP.